# mod_rewrite to redirect without changing the url in the browser?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In the general structure of the site is:

```
backend
- tralala
- tralala
- www
---- index.php
frontend
- tralala
- tralala
- www
---- index.php
common
- tralala
.htaccess
```

Domain eg `www.mysite.com`

Can I do something to register in `.htaccess`, so that when you go to `www.mysite.com` processed file `frontend/www/index.php` and then displays url `www.mysite.com`?  And if for example write `www.mysite.com/admin/` then to process the file `backend/www/index.php`?

In this case, all may be other options such as `www.mysite.com/game/gta/` (instead of `game/gta/` could be anything), and in this situation, in order to flag the file `frontend/www/index.php` with the following parameters (GET-type) `type=game&name=gta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these rules in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/
RewriteRule ^ /backend/www/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend|common)
RewriteRule ^ /frontend/www/index.php
```